# Api fetch responses Blob structure in React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, blob, fetch

I'm consuming a web api from my React Native Android project. After updating my react-native version to 0.60.3 my response data is not returning JSON, it returns Blob data structure.

This is what I get from **then(res=>{...})**

*Please look at the image*

[Screen-Shot-2019-07-18-at-17-25-10.png](https://postimg.cc/sBK286ys)

The **_bodyInit** object was returning JSON. But now it returns **Blob** that I can not reach from Js code.

I tried using functions **res.json()**, **res.text()**
They worked! But this time I just got data inside the *_bodyInit*. I can not reach other parameters like *ok*, *header* etc.

This is what I've tried. Like I said, *it works.* But it returns response with just my data, not other parameters like *ok*, *headers* etc.

```
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((res) => {
   if (res.ok) {
    // No 'ok' element anymore after .json()
  }
});
```

In the 'devtools' if I click the '_bodyInit' object. Simulator gives error below.

[Screen-Shot-2019-07-18-at-17-32-49.png](https://postimg.cc/sBVjKSMk)

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`ok` property is with response before you call `json` method on it. If your response contains json, call json to serialize body as json, if response contains blob, call .blob to serialize body as blob. See more proerties of Response [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

```
.then((res) => {
    console.log("response.ok", res.ok)

    // print headers,
    console.log("headers", res.headers.forEach(item=>console.log(item)))

    // if response if json, call res.json
    return res.json()
})
.then((res) => {
   // here you will only get json data, not other properties.
   console.log("json data is ", res)
});
```

Comment: First think is that I don't need blob data. I can use .json() for my project but before getting json data I need to check if request is **ok**

Comment: That looks better. Now I can check response parameters like *ok*. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I found two way to solve this problem.

1. Using *.then()* after using *.json()*

```
.then((res) => {
 if (res.ok) {
  res.json().then(res=>{
   console.log(res)
  })
 } else console.log("not ok")
});
```

2. Using ***async*** and ***await***

```
.then(async res => {
 if(res.ok) {
   const response = await res.json()
   console.log(response)
 } else console.log("not ok")
})
```

That would be great to see other solutions from you. Thanks.